# Google API request within a Mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I've hit a bump in the road with this one I simply can't get my head around how this should be done.

My question is I have a database full of coordinates, when the user enters their coordinates I want the query to return coordinates driving distances.
And then order them from closest to furthest.

Initially I was using a straight line to calculate distance using a formula but realized it wasn't very accurate as it didn't take into account streets, roads, etc.

Btw I'm coding in PHP and using MySQL as my database

Any help that will help me tackling this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to see that you are downvoted. You don't deserve this. But MySQL is by nature a domain specific language for operations on the MySQL databases. There do not exist general purpose libraries for MySQL as far as I am aware, and to try to create one would seem like a joke or esoteric exercise. The very syntax and semantics of the MySQL language bind it to this specific domain of use.